# Why these calls are having the same memory address?

Tags: c, memory

Recursive calls are put on system stack, that is what I have read. But If that is true, why in the program below I am getting same address for all of the rec() called. Shouldn't they have consecutive addresses on stack?

```
    void rec(int n )
    {

          printf("%d -> %p\n",n,rec);
          if( n ==0 )
                return;
          else
                rec(n-1);

    }
```

When I called rec(5) in my main() code, It gave the output as follows ,

```
 5 -> 0x4004f4
 4 -> 0x4004f4
 3 -> 0x4004f4
 2 -> 0x4004f4
 1 -> 0x4004f4
 0 -> 0x4004f4
```

Sorry, It if my query is too basic. But I am not able to come up with any explanation , except that it's due to some kind of compiler optimization. But I am not sure about it.Also kindly tell me any tool that can help me look at the program's memory(not size, but content) while it is running.

Thanks in Advance!!!

UPDATE:

I added a local variable i in each call, and I got what I wanted to see.

```
  5 -> 0x4004f4 0x7fff507d376c
  4 -> 0x4004f4 0x7fff507d373c
  3 -> 0x4004f4 0x7fff507d370c
  2 -> 0x4004f4 0x7fff507d36dc
  1 -> 0x4004f4 0x7fff507d36ac
  0 -> 0x4004f4 0x7fff507d367c
```

Thank You @EVERYONE :)

Comment: You are printed the address of rec, that has nothing to do with the stack.

Comment: If you want the stack address, try printing out the address of a local  variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why it is printing the same address?**

The function

```
 void rec(int n )
```

is in the code section of the memory (which is read only) and you are printing that same address where the function is located.

**To view memory**

You can use [objDump](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_objdump.htm),  [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/09/objdump-examples/) is how you use it.

Comment: Okay.. I got it @brokenfoot. Pretty Enlightening for me. Do you have any suggestion for my second question too ??

Comment: Try [ObjDump](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_objdump.htm), its [usage](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/09/objdump-examples/)

Answer (score 1):

No, the address of the function is static somewhere in memory.  What you are pushing on the stack during a recursive call is a return address and all the local variables that are in scope if the function.  [Here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.pgmgd.doc/c0925076137.htm) is a good tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

In your function, when you say:

```
printf("%d -> %p\n",n,rec);
```

You're asking for the address of the code for the function `rec(int)`. The compiler only creates the one copy of the function, so you're seeing this. There's no way (AFAIK) to access where on the stack you are from standard C.

Answer (score 1):

`rec` is function, and there is only one rec in your code, so no reason for address to be changed

Answer (score 0):

Function-calls are indeed placed on the stack, but they are not the function itself but the so-called *stack frame*. They contain parameters, local variables and the return address (and possibly more).

When you print the address of `rec` however, you don't get the address of the current stack frame, but the address of the code of the function. This is always the same because the code itself doesn't change.

You can see this in effect when you print the address of a local variable instead:

```
printf("%p -> %p\n", &n, rec);
```

Example output:

```
0028fee0 -> 004016d9
0028fec0 -> 004016d9
0028fea0 -> 004016d9
0028fe80 -> 004016d9
0028fe60 -> 004016d9
0028fe40 -> 004016d9
```

Note that while the second pointer stays the same (it's the function-pointer), the first changes every time, because there is a different `n`-variable in every call.